# adding peanut butter to a recipe

Tags: substitutions, cookies, butter, peanut-butter

Ok, so I saw [another question answered here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/62077/1672) that said:

> Natural Peanut butter is about 50% fat, butter is about 80% fat. If you want to maintain the original amount of fat in the recipe, you would decrease the butter by 60% of the amount of peanut butter you used.

I however have a recipe for oatmeal cookies that calls for 3/4 C of butter and I'd like to use a full cup of peanut butter, How do I adapt this correctly? I'm really bad at math and don't want to mess it up, haha.

Also if I'm adding that much peanut butter do I need to adjust any of the other ingredients like the flour or oats quantity?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: The reason I didn't quote the other post exactly is because I'm not using natural peanut butter, I'm going to use regular and I'm not sure of the fat % difference between the two.

Comment: Can you add a link to the other question? That can help people answer this one (just to have context, or to make sure they're not telling you something you already have read)

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/62055/how-to-adjust-oil-in-recipe-when-adding-peanut-butter?newreg=71dbaeacd4dd4a7c87fae19e6c5bf957

Comment: I think I'd like to see the entire recipe @DivinusOculus.